# MVC3 - Group Html Helper Extensions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I would like to group my html helper so that I could write in my view something simple as this:

```
@Html.SubGroup.MyCustomHelper("Hellow World")
```

instead of:

```
@Html.MyCustomHelper("Hellow World")
```

It appears that I cannot nest static classes in HtmlExtensions class that I use for all my helpers.

Any advices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do `@Html.SubGroup.MyCustomHelper("...")` because there's no such thing as an "extension property" and you don't control the `HtmlHelper` static class.

But you *could* do `@Html.SubGroup().MyCustomHelper("...")` with the extra parens as an extension method.

```
public static class MyHtmlHelpers
{
    public static MyHelpers SubGroup(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        return new MyHelpers(helper);
    }
}

public class MyHelpers
{
    public HtmlHelper Helper { get; private set; }

    public MyHelpers(HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        this.Helper = helper;
    }

    public MvcHtmlString MyCustomHelper(string someArgument)
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(someArgument);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would appreciate an example of such implementation

Comment: OK, I added a trivial (and untested!) example.

Comment: This is exactly what I did for my project.  I have methods like `Html.UITemplates().TextBox(...)` that automatically adds all common CSS classes, creates a proper label, and renders the textbox.  It also allows for chainability for certain common functions: `Html.UITemplates().ValidateRequired().MaxLength(50).TextBox(...)`.  It works very well, and I'd definitely recommend it!